# Is the Xgrid Controller still a 32-bit process?

Tags: mac-osx, cluster, grid, mac-osx-server

So Lion generally represented a pretty serious move toward 64-bit systems for Mac OS X. But while I was poking around the Lion Server: Advanced Administration guidelines here:

https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.7/#apd028B7F36-CEF3-46A8-B6CA-B138FCCFF527

I ran across this gem:

> If you are trying to submit jobs over 2 GB
>   The Xgrid controller is a 32-bit process and keeps most job input and output data in memory. This means that the controller can crash if your jobs require a large amount of input or produce a large amount of output.
>
> You can use a shared filesystem (such as Xsan or NFS) to share large amounts of data between distributed processes.

Is that text a holdover from an older version of the documentation, or is the Xgrid controller still really a 32-bit process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having run the XGrid controller process on a Lion Server, turns out it is indeed 64-bit. Hopefully, this means the issues with storing input and output data in memory - and the subsequent crashes for larger jobs - will be less of an issue.